# YouTube Search API gives me less videos than requested per page, but also gives me a nextPageToken

Tags: api, search, youtube, youtube-api

The query below (First Request) says there are 24 results, but only returns me 3 items (when I asked for 20 per page)... fine... but why is it also giving me a nextPageToken. I thought, well, maybe if I get less than the 20 I'm asking for, I'm at the end...

But... in another case below (Second and Third Requests) it said there were 1717 videos and it gave me the first 20, but when I got the next page it only gave me 5... also with a nextPageToken.

Note: this does include a location and radius parameter... maybe this is not quite baked yet.

The question, then, is how can I tell when I have reached the end of my results?

*(Edit: I found the reason for getting only 5 was that you still DO need to include maxResults along with nextPageToken, so maybe the answer is simply you're at the end if the nextPageToken is null or the number of items is less than resultsPerPage.)*

**First Request**

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?maxResults=20&type=video&order=rating&q=Stanford%20University&location=37.86854355%2C-122.502038433&locationRadius=6000m&key=AIzaSyDIOVCAngpI-xPkb30W5c6ee0PSBV9KbF8&part=id%2Csnippet

```
{
    "nextPageToken": "CBQQAA",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 24,
        "resultsPerPage": 20
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "id": {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "videoId": "WMfwyjJz9hs"
            },
        },
        {
            "id": {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "videoId": "aGnYxoGHYHQ"
            },
        },
        {
            "id": {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "videoId": "s50ZSCKA1zY"
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

**Second and Third Requests**

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?maxResults=20&type=video&order=rating&q=Sausalito&location=37.8590937%2C-122.4852507&locationRadius=6000m&key=AIzaSyDIOVCAngpI-xPkb30W5c6ee0PSBV9KbF8&part=id%2Csnippet

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?pageToken=CBQQAA&key=AIzaSyDIOVCAngpI-xPkb30W5c6ee0PSBV9KbF8&part=id%2Csnippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have similar trouble. I fixed bug by deleting field &order=rating in request. I think this parameter exclude videos with Zero(0) rating / this url return more results https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?maxResults=20&type=video&order=rating&q=Sausalito&location=37.8590937%2C-122.4852507&locationRadius=6000m&key=AIzaSyDIOVCAngpI-xPkb30W5c6ee0PSBV9KbF8&part=id%2Csnippet
Default order parameter value is 'relevance' returns similar result or you can try &order=viewCount parameter return similar result to